# How to apply a homomorphic filter (frequency highpass) only to a region of an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filtering, fft

I have the following function for homomorphic filtering of images:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import fftpack as fft
import numpy as np

def homomorphic_filter(img, low_cutoff=0.05, high_cutoff=0.5, order=2, boost=25):
    rows, cols = img.shape
    rh, rl, c = high_cutoff, low_cutoff, boost
    
    # Create a Gaussian filter
    x = np.linspace(-1, 1, cols)
    y = np.linspace(-1, 1, rows)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    d = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    mask = (rh - rl) * (1 - np.exp(-c * d**order)) + rl
    
    # Apply Homomorphic filtering
    img_log = np.log1p(img)
    img_fft = fft.fft2(img_log)
    img_fft_shift = fft.fftshift(img_fft)
    img_fft_filt = img_fft_shift * mask
    img_filt = np.real(fft.ifft2(fft.ifftshift(img_fft_filt)))
    img_exp = np.expm1(img_filt)
    img_norm = cv2.normalize(img_exp, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

    return img_norm

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread('/image_1.jpeg')

# Convert to HSI color space
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_image)

# Apply Homomorphic filtering on the entire Intensity channel
v_filtered = homomorphic_filter(v)
v_filtered = v_filtered.astype(np.uint8)  # Convert filtered intensity channel to the same type as hue and saturation channels

hsv_filtered = cv2.merge((h, s, v_filtered)) 
image_out = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_filtered, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)

# Display the images
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(image)
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(image_out)
plt.title('Homomorphic Filtered Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

When I apply it to an image to reduce unequal illumination, I works fine:

[image]

However, when there is a black background, I get this:

[image]

Any idea how to apply the filter only to the non zero region of the second image?

Original images are here: [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVaQ0.jpg), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3U9O.jpg)

Comment: It is the Gaussian filter that causes this. You can use a [normalized convolution](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/PIRODDI1/NormConv/NormConv.html) instead of a plain convolution to avoid blurring across the edge of the mask. It is easy to implement,  but DIPlib has an implementation specifically for the Gaussian filter: https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/linear.html#dip-NormalizedConvolution-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-FloatArray-CL-dip-String-CL-dip-StringArray-CL-dip-dfloat-